# Accessing a USB drive after start up with Python

Tags: raspbian, usb, python

I'm working on a picture viewer using python, that executes on startup of X (using LXDE/autostart) and accesses an attached USB drive and starts to display the images it finds. I'm using the current version of Raspbian Wheezy.

I have had to put a delay of 60 seconds on the script (using time.sleep) before it starts looking for images, because if I don't Python reports it can find the USB drive but there are no files present. This means there is quite a delay from reaching the desktop to the picture viewer starting. Is there a clever way in Python of getting round this and not having a delay?

Answer (score 2):

#### dbus

You'd probably want to interface with **dbus** and listen for usb activity.

There is an example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/471099/416646) StackOverflow post.

There is a tutorial available [here](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html), which may give you a better understanding of what dbus is, and how to interface with it in python.

#### fstab

Is the problem the fact that the device isn't getting mounted automatically, and your system is waiting for your X Window System to decide what to do?

- `sudo blkid`

  - Identify the blkid of your partition/device
- `sudo vim /etc/fstab`

  - `UUID=b756693e-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXcb3aXXXX /mnt/usb-mount               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0  1`

Answer (score 0):

You can list your USB drive mounted or not via Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
partitionsFile = open("/proc/partitions")
lines = partitionsFile.readlines()[2:]#Skips the header lines
for line in lines:
    words = [x.strip() for x in line.split()]
    minorNumber = int(words[1])
    deviceName = words[3]
    if minorNumber % 16 == 0:
        path = "/sys/class/block/" + deviceName
        if os.path.islink(path):
            if os.path.realpath(path).find("/usb") > 0:
                print "/dev/%s" % deviceName
```

Then if your device mounted you can do what ever you want with your code.

Answer (score 0):

with a few changes to @gurcanozturk's answer.  The following code will auto mount the usb drive as /mnt/usb.  Tested on raspberry pi.

Note: You would need to run this python code as root.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
partitionsFile = open("/proc/partitions")
lines = partitionsFile.readlines()[2:] #Skips the header lines
for line in lines:
    words = [x.strip() for x in line.split()]
    minorNumber = int(words[1])
    deviceName = words[3]
        if minorNumber % 16 == 0:
        path = "/sys/class/block/" + deviceName
        if os.path.islink(path):
            if os.path.realpath(path).find("/usb") > 0:
                print ("/dev/%s1 -> /mnt/usb" %(deviceName))
                os.system('mkdir /mnt/usb 2>/dev/null') # if already created don't output error.
                os.system("mount /dev/%s1 /mnt/usb 2>/dev/null"%(deviceName))
```